# Como disparar uma mensagem a cada click no jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Eu tenho um `form` para calcular o índice IMC, sendo que a cada click em um botão exibe uma  div mensagem com o resultado do cálculo, porém eu quero que a mensagem seja exibida uma **única vez por clique**. Esta imagem apresenta o meu código atual:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o Script de evento onclick para exibir a mensagem div na tela:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#botao").click(function(){

        var altura = parseFloat($("#altura").val());
        var peso = $("#peso").val();
        var quadrado = (altura * altura);
        var calculo = (peso /quadrado);
        var imc = (calculo *10000).toFixed(2);
        if(imc<=18.5){
            $('#mensagem').append('<b>Seu IMC é de <b>'+imc+' Abaixo do Peso</b></p>');
        }
        else if (imc>18.50 && imc<=24.99){
            $('#mensagem').append('<b>Seu IMC é de <b>'+imc+' Saudável, entre 18,6 e 24,9</b></p>');
        }else if (imc>24.90 && imc<=29.99){
            $('#mensagem').append('<b>Seu IMC é de <b>'+imc+' Você está com sobrepeso</b></p>');
        }else if (imc>29.99 && imc<=34.99 ){
            $('#mensagem').append('<b>Seu IMC é de <b>'+imc+' Obesidade Grau I</b></p>');
        }else if (imc>34.99 && imc<=39.99 ){
            $('#mensagem').append('<b>Seu IMC é de <b>'+imc+' Obesidade Grau II (severa)</b></p>');
        }else if (imc>39.99 ){
            $('#mensagem').append('<b>Seu IMC é de <b>'+imc+'Obesidade Grau III (mórbida), entre acima de 40</b></p>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Testa mudar de `$('#mensagem').append` para `$('#mensagem').html`, assim sobrepões o conteúdo da div `#mensagem`. É isso que procuravas?

Comment: o que vc quer dizer por mensagem?  Uma menssagem de alerta (pop up)? Uma mensagem na div dentro da página?

Comment: @Sergio era apenas isto mesmo, eu esqueci que o append ele iria adicionar linhas a cada clique, o html realmente sobrepõe, resolveu meu problema. Obrigado!

Comment: @IvanFloripa vi que já aceitas-te uma resposta. Coloquei uma nova resposta na mesma com uma sugestão de melhoramento no código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque todos as funções `append` por `html`. E certifique de resetar a div #mensagem com `$("#mensagem").html("");`

Comment: Rafael resolvido o problema Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Use assim:

```
$('#mensagem').html('<b>Seu IMC é de <b>'+imc+' Obesidade Grau II (severa)</b></p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Como tinha referido o `.append()` acrescenta conteúdo ao que já existe. Tens de usar o `.html()` que substitui o contéudo. Tendo dito isso acho que podias fazer isso assim, mais organizado e fácil de manter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mensagens = { // lógica das mensagens
        '18.5': 'Abaixo do Peso',
        '24.99': 'Saudável, entre 18,6 e 24,9',
        '29.99': 'Você está com sobrepeso',
        '34.99': 'Obesidade Grau I',
        '39.99': 'Obesidade Grau II (severa)',
        '1000': 'Obesidade Grau III (mórbida)',
    };
    var imcs = Object.keys(mensagens).map(Number); // para ter escalões com numeros

    $("#botao").click(function() {

        var altura = parseFloat($("#altura").val());
        var peso = parseFloat($("#peso").val());
        var calculo = peso / (altura * altura);
        var imc = (calculo * 10000).toFixed(2);
        var escala = imcs[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < imcs.length; i++) {
            if (imc > imcs[i]) break; // caso tenha ultrapassado ele usa o ultimo valor registado no loop 
            escala = imcs[i] + '';
        }
        var texto = ['<b>Seu IMC é de <b>', imc, '.'].join(''); // texto
        var nota = ['Escalão: ', mensagens[escala]].join(''); // nota
        $("#mensagem").html([texto, nota].join('<br />')); // inserir no DOM
    });
});
```